# PHPUnit and mock request from Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit, guzzle

I have a class with the following function :

```
public function get(string $uri) : stdClass
{
    $this->client = new Client;
    $response = $this->client->request(
        'GET',
        $uri,
        $this->headers
    );

    return json_decode($response->getBody());
}
```

How can I mock the request method from PHPUnit? I tried different ways but it always tries to connect to the uri specified.

I tried with :

```
    $clientMock = $this->getMockBuilder('GuzzleHttp\Client')
        ->setMethods('request')
        ->getMock();

    $clientMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('request')
        ->willReturn('{}');
```

But this didn't work. What can I do? I just need to mock the response to be empty.

Thanks

PD : Client comes from (use GuzzleHttp\Client)

Comment: how is `$this->client` initialized and how do you actually pass the mock?

Comment: Don't you need to return an object implementing ResponseInterface instead of a string? Otherwise it'll blow up when you call `getBody`.

Comment: sure, your mock should return a `ResponseInterface` stub so that `getBody` works (you will have to mock this also)

Comment: Also http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html might be better instead of the PHPUnit mocks

Comment: I wanted to use phpunit mocks

Comment: Should nt it be "->setMethods(['request'])"?

Comment: Or leave `setMethods` off completely, it'll mock them all

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think as suggested is better to use http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#mock-handler

as it looks like the most elegant way to do it properly.

Thank you all

Comment: URLs (fixed and regexps-based) mock handler for Guzzle 6 - [tarampampam/guzzle-url-mock](https://github.com/tarampampam/guzzle-url-mock)

Comment: Is this the best way?  I don't see a way to verify that you are sending the correct parameters to the guzzle client, just mocking responses.

Answer (score 2):

The mocked Response doesn't need to be anything in particular, your code just expects it to be an object with a `getBody` method.  So you can just use a `stdClass`, with a `getBody` method which returns some `json_encoded` object.  Something like:

```
$jsonObject = json_encode(['foo']);
$uri = 'path/to/foo/bar/';

$mockResponse = $this->getMockBuilder(\stdClass::class)->getMock();

$mockResponse->method('getBody')->willReturn($jsonObject);

$clientMock = $this->getMockBuilder('GuzzleHttp\Client')->getMock();

$clientMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('request')
    ->with(
        'GET', 
        $uri,
        $this->anything()
    )
    ->willReturn($mockResponse);

$result = $yourClass->get($uri);

$expected = json_decode($jsonObject);

$this->assertSame($expected, $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this way to mock a Client in PHP. In this example I am using Guzzle Client.

Clone the code or install it via composer

```
$ composer require doppiogancio/mocked-client
```

And then...

```
$builder = new HandlerStackBuilder();

// Add a route with a response via callback
$builder->addRoute(
    'GET', '/country/IT', static function (ServerRequestInterface $request): Response {
        return new Response(200, [], '{"id":"+39","code":"IT","name":"Italy"}');
    }
);

// Add a route with a response in a text file
$builder->addRouteWithFile('GET',  '/country/IT/json', __DIR__ . '/fixtures/country.json');

// Add a route with a response in a string
$builder->addRouteWithFile('GET',  '{"id":"+39","code":"IT","name":"Italy"}');

// Add a route mocking directly the response
$builder->addRouteWithResponse('GET', '/admin/dashboard', new Response(401));

$client = new Client(['handler' => $builder->build()]);
```

Once you have mocked the client you can use it like this:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/country/DE/json');
$body = (string) $response->getBody();
$country = json_decode($body, true);

print_r($country);

// will return
Array
(
    [id] => +49
    [code] => DE
    [name] => Germany
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the current answer about using MockHandler, it's possible to process the request so that you can validate the calls.

The following example passes a callable which just tests the request method and throws an exception if not POST, if that is OK it returns the response.  The principle can be expanded to test other details about the request...

```
    $mock = new MockHandler([
        function ($request) {
            $this->assertEquals('POST', $request->getMethod());

            return new Response(
                200,
                [],
                json_encode([ "access_token" => '1234e' ])
            );
        },
        new Response(
            200,
            [],
            json_encode([ "details" =>
                [
                    [
                        "orderID" => 229783,
                    ],
                    [
                        "orderID" => 416270,
                    ],
                ],
            ])
        ),
    ]);

    $handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
    $client = new Client(['handler' => $handler]);
```

So the first call to the client has the test included, the second call just returns a response.

Just noticed that any time you use a callable to process the request, you MUST return a Response object if you expect the process to continue.