# How to create mock request for Guzzle in UnitTest? (PHP, Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, guzzle

**Issue description:**

It is not possible to create Mock request in UnitTest. I'm using Guzzle in Laravel.

I am sanding request in Laravel with Guzzle. This is in code file class. Example:

```
$client = new Client(['cookies' => true]);
    $client->request('GET', 'https://some-test-url.com/provider/v2/oauth2/authorize',
      ['connect_timeout' => 30]);
```

In UnitTest class file in test, I'm creating Mock request.

```
$mock = new MockHandler([
        new Response(200,
          ['Set-Cookie' => 'cookie1=cookie1_data; Domain=some-test-url.com',
          'cookie2=cookie2_data; Domain=some-test-url.com',
          'cookie3=cookie3_data; Domain=some-test-url.com',] , 'Test response'),
    ]);

    $handlerStack = HandlerStack::create($mock);
    $client = new Client(['handler' => $handlerStack, 'cookies' => true]);
```

After running UnitTest the test are passing. The issue is that Mock request is not implemented. The test is hitting API URL: *https://some-test-url.com/provider/v2/oauth2/authorize*. When I turn off the internet I'm getting error:

```
 cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: some-test-url.com (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://some-test-url.com/provider/v2/oauth2/authorize
```

I want to crate UnitTests and that tests are reading Mock data and not hitting the API.

Do you know is it possible to write mock test for Guzzle in Laravel? If it is how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPUnit and mock request from Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013014/phpunit-and-mock-request-from-guzzle)

Comment: Yes I did without success. Also I have tried with https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#mock-handler but also without success.

Comment: How are you sending or binding your $client from your test case, to the code that is being executed by the test case?

Comment: @mrhn Thank you for response. That was the issue. I have instanced two Clients. To creating valid test I need to use one Client for tests and in code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Issue Solved**

I have instanced two Clients. For creating valid test I needed to use same Client for tests class and in code class.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using `Guzzle` instead of a known facade called [`Http`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#testing). That facade solves all your issues, in a simpler and more straightforward way...

You have a lot of possibilities to play with it, and is easier and more "laravel way", try to stick with it and stop using `Guzzle`